# Nanosecond Precision Variable Timer for Kernel 4.X using CLOCK_REALTIME

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, kernel

I have been working on timers for a while but still unable to get a promising solution for my situation.

Basically, I want to send packets at specific time.
For example :

1st PACKET at 1486500720.000000000

-> wait -> nanosleep(1000000000)

2nd PACKET at 1486500721.000000000

-> wait -> nanosleep(1000000000)

3rd PACKET at 1486500722.000000000

-> wait -> nanosleep(1000000000)

4th PACKET at 1486500723.000000000

The time gap between them is exactly 1.000000000 second but when I send packet, each time it takes different time.

For example for 1st Packet, it takes 0.005025045 seconds to send it and then the nanosleep start.

So, my second packet is sent at 486500721.005025045 instead of 1486500721.000000000.

So everytime I have to adjust the nanosleep value by using clockgettime(CLOCK_REALTIME) by subtracting the time remaining with including offset of getime command overhead.

As I have to this in a loop with nanosecond precision (I know it is not possible but I want it to be as specific as possible), I use simple for loop.

My question is there any better way to do this with more precision ? I am on Kernel 4.4, so are you aware of any approach which is working for newer kernels or any other approach likely to be more precise than mine ?

Comment: Set yourself a timer with `timer_create()`.

Comment: @EOF: That would not guarantee less jitter. OP: you cannot have nanosecond precision in Linux or any other full-grown OS. Even for an RTOS, there is a lower limit which is most likely much largter than that (RT does not guarantee "no jitter").  It sonds like an XY-problem. What is your **actual** and specific problem?

Comment: @Olaf: Sure, you'll get *statistical* jitter. But unlike the OP's current approach, there shouldn't be much (any) *systematic* change in phase.

Comment: @EOF: It depends on what OP wants. From the question it is not clear.

Comment: @Olaf: It seems to me the OP wants to send multiple packets, one each second. Seems fairly obvious to me.

Comment: @EOF: Which is already a problem, as he only has some control over queuing them, not when they are sent. But we have no idea how much jitter is tolerable for him, considering he uses `nanosleep`, not usleep, etc. which are sufficient for 1s timing. And he asks for "nanosecond precision", which implies he wants to have very low jitter. (which "statistically" alyway increas the delay, never reduce, so it does not average to zero).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `clock_nanosleep`, which allows an absolute time to wait until, rather than `nanosleep`, which only uses relative times. However there's no way you're going to get the degree of precision you're asking for. Just returning to userspace after the clock expires is going to take at least a few hundred nanoseconds if not a thousand or more. And then there's unpredictable latency to send the packet after you wake, too.

At best you might be able to tune your wake time too be "close enough" for your purposes.

Comment: I'd recommend setting an interval timer with `timer_create()` instead.

Comment: @EOF: Why? I would strongly recommend against that, since signal handlers are an awful context to run in - a thread calling `clock_nanosleep` is a much better context to be in with regards to how you can interact with the rest of the program. Neither should have any performance/timing benefit over the other.

Comment: You don't have to run any code in a signal handler, `timer_create()` can run the code in a thread context. Alternatively, you can `sigwait()`. Either way, using an interval timer avoids shifting the wait-time by the time the code executes between the waits.

Comment: @EOF: Your comments indicate a lack of research on the topic. glibc's implementation of thread delivery for timers creates the new thread at every timer expiration, adding **huge** latency and silently dropping timer expirations if thread creation fails. It's unusably bad. `clock_nanosleep`, with an absolute expiry time, **already** avoids having to shift the wait time, because you don't pass a wake time; you pass a wakeup time.

Comment: Thank You for this Approach. I figured it out the same this morning. It is exactly what I wanted. Thank You very much :-)